# Mechanical Turk Sandbox: Worker Account Issue

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to follow [Solomon Messing's guide to using MTurkR](http://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/streamline-your-mechanical-turk-workflow-with-mturkr/) to programmatically create Turk HITs. While  I seem to successfully create HITs from my MTurk Requester sandbox, they don't appear on my Worker Sandbox. In fact, the Account Tab on the Worker Sandbox says 'This data is temporarily unavailable' and the HITs tab displays 'Your request was not completed successfully'. Any thoughts on debugging this are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean they don't appear on "my worker sandbox"? You're searching for the HITs by title and they're not showing up, or something else?

Comment: (Unsuccesfully) searched by title, description, and by HitID

Comment: Can you include the details of your code in your question?

Comment: Certainly - http://pastebin.com/UYP0imMW

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is how you're specifying the `sandbox` parameter. Note that every MTurkR function can operate on the sandbox or the live server. The default is the live server, unless you tell it otherwise. Your code creates the HIT in the sandbox but then you check to see its status on the live server (by not including a `sandbox = TRUE` argument in `HITStatus`).

[As you can see here](https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=30L3LKLDHM3G5NBRKULH6TTNMGJSKE), your HIT is posted to the sandbox so the `CreateHIT` operation was successful.

You either need to pass `sandbox = TRUE` to all function calls, or use the global option `options(MTurkR.sandbox = TRUE)`, which will allow you to operate in the sandbox without specifying it explicitly in each function call. This is helpful if you want to run your code on the sandbox to try it out and then run the same code on the live server: you can just change the global option and then everything will run as intended on the live server.